# subclassing int in a Cython extension type using __new__

Tags: cython, subclassing

I want to cythonize code that uses a subclass of "int", which behaves actually like a set (similar to [C++ bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)).

The pure python object is instantiated with `__new__`:

```py
class BitSet(int):
    def __new__(cls, intlist=()):
        val = 0
        for k in intlist:
            val |= (1<<k)
        return super().__new__(cls, val)
```

However, if I try to make this a Cython type extension like so:

```py
cdef class BitSet(int):
    def __new__(cls, intlist=()):
        # ...
```

The compilers throws an error:

```
__new__ method of extension type will change semantics in a future version of Pyrex and Cython. Use __cinit__ instead.
```

After reading the documentation on [`__cinit__` and `__init__`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init), I don't see exactly how to use them, because `__cinit__` should not return a value.

However, I tried the following that compiles:

```py
cdef class BitSet(int):
    cdef BitSet __new__(cls, intlist=()):
        # ...
```

Using `__cinit__` like below also compiles, but I am not sure it is valid, because it looks like we instantiating a base `int`:

```py
cdef class BitSet(int):
    def __cinit__(self, intlist=()):
        val = 0
        for k in intlist:
            val |= (1<<k)
        self = val
```

What approach would you use to cythonize such class, and is it actually relevant? For further details, I want my class to have the following methods behave like sets:

- `__len__`: number of bits set to 1 (i.e. number of elements in the set)
- `__bool__`: True if the set is not empty
- `__iter__`: iterate over integer elements
- `__contains__`: test if an integer is in the bitset
- `__sub__`: difference of sets
- etc

And I also want to disable some int methods that are not suited, such as `__float__`, `__neg__`, `__pow__`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really sound like a subclass of `int` in the sense that it has a substantially different interface to `int`. It can't (or shouldn't) really be used in place of an `int`. It sounds more like it's implemented in term of `int`. So perhaps you should do that instead?

You're right that `__cinit__` doesn't do what you want. Your version with `self = val` definitely won't work - it'll just reassign the `self` reference within the function.

In Cython 3. you're kind of stuck on using a `cdef class` anyway because:

```
TypeError: inheritance from PyVarObject types like 'int' not currently supported
```

In Cython 0.29.x you get away with it because it isn't checked. However, it'll fall apart if you add anything to the type (e.g. a `cdef` member, a non-static `cdef` method). It's so easy to break it that I really don't recommend it. Essentially anything you add to the class will overlay and corrupt the data of the underlying `int`.

If you insisted on using a `cdef class` is probably a `staticmethod` constructor function:

```
cdef class BitSet(int)
    @staticmethod
    def make_bitset(intlist):
        val = 0
        for k in intlist:
            val |= (1<<k)
        return Bitset(val)
```

That doesn't prevent people from just calling the constructor themselves of course.

You could obviously use a non-`cdef class` and that would work.

---

In summary, this isn't really "correct" use of inheritance, what you want to do isn't *really* supported by `cdef classes`, and using a `cdef class` gives you huge opportunities to corrupt data and break things because older versions of Cython didn't have a check to stop you from doing it.

Comment: Indeed, the need for 'int' is for the implementation, not for the actual interface. When you say
“So perhaps you should do that instead?”, 
you say I should not inherit from `int`, but have an attribute `self.value` that I use for every operation? I avoided that thinking it would add more code, and more overhead, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes - that's roughly what I was proposing. It'd add a little overhead but Python/Cython doesn't really have the concept of "private inheritance" (which is what you'd use in C++ for this kind of implementation detail). Alternatively, why not use a C++ vector or a malloc'd array for your data storage rather than a Python int?

Comment: Or even an `array.array`